# Angular 4 deep linking does not work after ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, nginx

I want to load my Angular application to the respective screen when the user pastes the below URLs into the browser:

1. http://localhost/screen1 (should show screen1)
2. http://localhost/screen2 (should show screen2)

I have created 2 components - Screen1Component and Screen2Component for the above two paths.

screen1.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-screen1',
templateUrl: './screen1.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./screen1.component.css']
})
export class Screen1Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

screen2.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-screen2',
    templateUrl: './screen2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./screen2.component.css']
})
export class Screen2Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

In order to load these modules from my base route I made them children components of the base path '', like this, in routing.module.ts:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {Screen1Component} from './screen1/screen1.component';
import {Screen2Component} from './screen2/screen2.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'screen1',
                component: Screen1Component
            },
            {
                path: 'screen2',
                component: Screen2Component
            }
        ]
    }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here's my main.ts:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {Screen1Component} from './screen1/screen1.component';
import {Screen2Component} from './screen2/screen2.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'screen1',
                component: Screen1Component
            },
            {
                path: 'screen2',
                component: Screen2Component
            }
        ]
    }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Screen1Component} from './screen1/screen1.component';
import {Screen2Component} from './screen2/screen2.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
}
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {Screen1Component} from './screen1/screen1.component';
import {Screen2Component} from './screen2/screen2.component';
import {routing} from './routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, Screen1Component, Screen2Component],
    imports: [BrowserModule, routing],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The app.component.html:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tryout</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do npm start, i.e. ng serve -o, I am able to lazy load and deep link to these components. After making a production build with the command ng build --prod, I know that we need to directly use the generated files from the dist folder and copy them to a web server. I ran http-server -o (you need to npm install http-server -g to use the server) after cd'ing into the dist folder, but the components do not deep link at all.

I even copied them to the root folder of my Nginx server, i.e. {nginx-installation-home}/html folder.

What happens in both these cases is that when I hit the URL: http://localhost/, my index.html loads the app successfully. But when I hit the URL http://localhost/screen1 or http://localhost/screen2, I see a 404 not found.

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try using hash strategy or configure nginx server to redirect all requests to index.html https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Comment: I did that, but not working for me :(

Comment: Thanks yurzui for the help. Earlier I had tried this, but I guess something was wrong at that time. This worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a non empty route path to have children under it.

So use them without children as below,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'screen1',component: Screen1Component},
    {path: 'screen2',component: Screen2Component}},
    {path: '',redirectTo:'/screen1',pathMatch:'full'}
];
```

Also, note that first match will be picked up as per angular route configuration.

The issue was with the server configuration for routing strategies. The app works in lite-server but not in others.

Comment: I did that. But this did not work after prod build on my server. My exact problem is that everything seems to be working great in ng server but not after ng build --prod.

Comment: As mentioned by you, I should redirect to screen1. Why should I do this if I want to display another component on my base route?

Comment: you have no component on your base route. So it will pick the `' '` and give it to you since no component is associated with it you get a blank page with 404

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: How do you make components deep link / lazy load from the browser on a production build?

Comment: Yes I am available on TeamViewer

Comment: reach me in fb @ aravind2109

Comment: Thanks for all the help Avavind! Eventually like you said in our TeamViewer session, I configured my Nginx web server with settings as shared by yurzui - https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Comment: @SamirJoglekar Happy to help you.. can u send me the summary which we discused

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine and will behave correctly with ng serve or lite-server. I needed to configure my Nginx server with settings as shown here - https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers